# Refreshing specific parent resolve cache

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Is it possible to cache-bust/refresh specific resolves in the parent resolves? Or even disable ui-router resolve caching for specific items?

I have this setup where `company` is provided to 2 child states by an abstract parent state. `controller.dashboard.company` makes an update to this object but when the user navigates to `dashboard.overview` and comes back to `dashboard.company`, the old resolve's values are loaded. Only a hard-refresh of the page gets the new data from the API.

**router.js**

```
.state('dashboard', {
  abstract: true,
  resolve: {
    company: ['api.company', 'user', function ($company, user) {
        return $company.id(user.company);
    }]
  }
})
.state('dashboard.overview', {
  url: '/',
  templateUrl: 'dashboard/overview/overview.html',
  controller: 'controller.dashboard.overview',
  resolve: { ... more API calls ... }
})
.state('dashboard.company', {
  url: '/company',
  templateUrl: 'dashboard/company/company.html',
  controller: 'controller.dashboard.company',
  resolve: { ... more API calls ... }
})
```

I can call `$state.reload();` but this refetches every resolve from the `dashboard` downwards, which is about 30 different states which shouldn't be refetched.

I'm caching the company object in-memory via a service (`api.company`) but since the resolve doesn't re-fire, the service cache is never queried again.

Any ideas?

*Angular 1.6.8 / ui-router 1.0.14*

Answer (score 0):

try and add it to your transitions.Onstart function

```
 $transitions.onStart({},function ($transition) {
    console.log("\n %c From: " + $transition.$from() + " To: " + 
    $transition.$to() + "\n\n");
      $transition.addResolves({ company: ['api.company', 'user', function  
            $company, user) {
            return $company.id(user.company);
        }]
     });
   })
```

Comment: I get a "TypeError: $transition$.addResolve is not a function" error:

$transitions.onStart({}, function ($transition$) {
            $transition$.addResolve({
                company: ['api.company', 'user', function ($company, user) {
                    return $company.id(user.company);
                }]
            });
        });

Comment: Turns out the method was renamed to `addResolvable` but unfortunately this doesn't update the cached resolve value. When the controller is run again after a route change, it loads the older version. I've tried running the addResolved in `app.run`, local controller and parent controller!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up moving the "company" resolve into the immediate children states, letting my factory level cache to keep it hydrated. So, still no API calls were made but I was getting the latest `company` between route parent changes. This allows the `company` to be updated from the factory cache when moving between `dashboard.overview.*` and `dashboard.company.*` routes.